# возможно ли из pdf viewer убрать возможность загрузки и печати?

Tags: javascript, pdf, загрузка, печать

есть такой вопрос. Есть файлик в формате pdf на сайте, который нужно просматривать, но скачивать или печатать нельзя, он открывается просто ссылкой на файл стандартным google pdf viewer. Могу ли я на уровне не браузера, а сайта как то запретить загрузку и печать этого файла? если нет то как это реализовать? сторонними плагинами для просмотра pdf?

Answer (score 2):

Технически запретить скачивать pdf нельзя - потому что браузер все равно должен его скачать чтобы отобразить. С печатью то же самое - скачав документ пользователь всегда сможет открыть его локально и напечатать.

Тем не менее, вы можете закрыть скачивание для неспециалистов если сделаете свой просмотрщик pdf (например, на базе [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)) (но специалист просто найдет прямую ссылку на pdf в инструментах разработчика и откроет ее напрямую).

Запрет печати страницы можно сделать средствами CSS:

```
@media print {
  body {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```